# Can astyle handle array initialization braces different?

Tags: c++, astyle

I have the following code snippet, which is exactly like I want it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (auto i: { 1, 2, 3 })
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately astyle turns this into:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (auto i :
            {
                1, 2, 3
            })
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make astyle treat initializer lists braces differently(i.e. ignore them)?

These are my current options:

```
--mode=c --style=allman --indent=spaces=4 -max-code-length=100 --attach-namespaces --pad-oper --pad-header
```

Comment: is not my intent to preach one software or another, but have you considered using clang format instead?

Answer (score 2):

Just add option `--keep-one-line-blocks`
so, all option are

*--mode=c --style=allman --indent=spaces=4 --max-code-length=100 --attach-namespaces --pad-oper --pad-header **--keep-one-line-blocks***

---

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    for ( auto i : { 1, 2, 3 } )
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    bool br = false;
    if ( true )
    {   br = true; cout << "Just test" << endl; }
}
```

However, you should be careful. 
After adding `--keep-one-line-blocks` option, astyle just keeps all one line blocks such as last line.